# Android stack trace shows test code in production Firebase crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crash, crashlytics

The exception is being reported in Firebase crashlytics for the play store version of the app. This happens when the user is landed on the launch activity. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

There is no other stack traces available that is helpful to trace the code where it is happening.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void androidx.test.internal.platform.ThreadChecker.checkNotMainThread()"
       at androidx.test.internal.util.Checks.checkNotMainThread(Checks.java:1)
       at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.postAsynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:1)
       at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:2)
       at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:7)
       at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridStateExtractor.tryExtractingScreenState(HybridStateExtractor.java:7)
       at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridStateExtractor.getStableScreen(HybridStateExtractor.java:2)
       at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.handlePerformScrape(RemotePlatform.java:1)
       at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.messageLoop(RemotePlatform.java:55)
       at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.lambda$startCrawlAndWaitUntilFinished$0$androidx-test-tools-crawler-platform-RemotePlatform(RemotePlatform.java:1)
       at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(RemotePlatform.java:6)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

No tests nor any UI test dependencies are added in the project. Is there any chance this might be caused by any of the 3rd party libraries? Like FacebookSDK, Braze, Branch or Firebase Crashlytics?

Comment: How did you solve this problem..? Can you please tell me

Comment: It was not anything in my code base, since we don't have any dependencies of test libraries. As Till mentioned in the answer, it was someone who is testing the application against AndroidXApp Crawler and it crashed. For some reason it is showing up in the Firebase Crashlytics. So I have muted it and all the devices that are affected are emulators.

Comment: Oh Okay. Can you guide me please how to  ignore or mute this in google play console? Because this error showing when I release as internal testing on pre-launch report. Error in Google Pixel 2 (virtual), Android version 9 (SDK28)

Comment: Any solution for this error? The accepted answer is not a perfect one.

Comment: @Karthik how you know the tests was using emulator not real device from crashlytics?

Comment: The processor was Intel Xeon under device details :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make absolutely sure that you **don't** include test code (e.g. espresso) in your production app. Code using these libraries is intended to **test** your app code, not to be used to build app functionality.

This code should only reside in the `app/src/test` (unit tests) and `app/src/androidTest` (instrumentation tests, e.g. using espresso) directories. When setting up these libraries in your `build.gradle`, make sure to specify the dependency with `androidTestImplementation` (or `testImplementation` for unit test libs), like:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-beta01'
```

This way, you prevent yourself from even using it in the wrong place, i.e. application code.

Comment: I am ashamed to say, that we have 0 tests for our app. xD And also there is no dependencies added for espresso in the application. Do you think its because on of the 3rd party libraries we use producing this crash, like FacebookSDK, Braze, Branch? The only thing is its impossible to trace which one is causing this crash since there is no info on the stack trace. :'(

Comment: Ah okay. Looking again at this, it mentions the [androidx App Crawler](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/other-testing-tools/app-crawler), so if that's nothing you are using, then maybe someone tried to crawl your app (unsuccessfully). And that shouldn't concern you.

Comment: @Till Can I remove androidTestImplementation  from build.gradle file? I mean I am going to launch the app in google play store.. Is it necessary to put these libs?

Comment: @Till Is that a security issue I need to concern about?

Comment: @Andrew If you only have it because it's been included in the initial default project setup, then you can just remove it together with the test and androidTest folders. But either way it has no implication for the release build that you publish to Google Play because these test dependencies will not be included.

Comment: @Karthik not that I'm aware of

Comment: @Till I am still getting ``` Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void androidx.test.internal.platform.ThreadChecker.checkNotMainThread()" ``` in google play console. I have check my code I didn't include any test code like espresso. But still getting same can you please help me out